# C++ Input byte and output hex

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Hey I've been out of the C++ game for a long time now and trying to get back into it. I'm trying to start of with some basic stuff that can actually be useful to me as well. I'm trying to input bytes such as

14 A4 B7 54 85

and output it like this with comma separator

0x14, 0xA4, 0xB7, 0x54, 0x85

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Suggestions? Yes, read a good introductory book on the subject :-) Or at least *try* something first.

Comment: Treat the numbers as words (std::string).  Input one word, print the 0x, then the number, then output a comma.  The final number is tricky, as it doesn't have a comma.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes I am currently reading one of my favorite C++ books. I was reading up if i needed regex or boost to do this and i've never used either those before so trying to read into all those as well.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks i'll look into that. I remember reading somewhere you can determine the end of the string like you can with eof. Will have to look into that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are literally hundreds of ways you could do this (and none strikes me as a particularly compelling reason to use C++ instead of any number of other possibilities), but I'd probably do it something like this:

```
std::ifstream in("my input.hex");
std::ofstream out("my output.txt");

std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
               infix_ostream_iterator<std::string>(out, ","),
               [](std::string const &s) { return "0x"s + s; });
```

Using the [`infix_ostream_iterator`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/13176/489) I've posted elsewhere.